# Adicionar AndEngine como uma biblioteca para o meu projeto no Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

Estou tentando importar o projeto `AndEngine`pelo Github e posteriormente adicionar a extenção `AndEngine Physics Box2D`.

Estou fazendo os passos:

1. Criei meu projeto
2. Instalei o Git e adicionei o caminho C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe nas configurações
3. Em VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git, adicionei a URL dos projetos `AndEngine.git`e `AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.git` e cliquei em "clone".

O processo é realizado com sucesso mas quando termina, pergunta se eu quero adicionar um novo projeto com o nome `AndEngine` e outro com o nome `AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension`.

De qualquer forma, são criados os diretórios fora do meu projeto.

Minha dúvida é como eu adiciono AndEngine como `library` no meu projeto do Android Studio.

Um exemplo do problema é que não reconhece o SimpleBaseGameActivity e EngineOptions do meu código.

**Meu Código**

```
import android.transition.Scene;

/**
* Created by lmontanhine on 20/1/2015.
*/
public class GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Android Studio é baseado no GRADLE, ou seja, entende-se projeto como sendo um aglomerado do módulos. No seu caso você precisa dar clone nos projetos do Git e depois importa-los como módulos no seu projeto.

Depois ter feito isso, você só precisa adicionar esses novos módulos nas dependências do projeto principal. :-)

Comment: Opa, entendi. Seria semelhante a importar o sdk do Facebook, por exemplo. Vou tentar fazer dessa forma e se der certo, aviso aqui. Obrigado @Felipe Bonezi

Comment: Isso mesmo! :-)